# How to Customize Theme in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress. 
could anyone suggest me wordpress tutorial which help me customize a theme from scratch and how to create template file in that theme . i searched in google but failed to find a good tutorial.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Customize WordPress Themes:**

Depending on the theme you're using for your WordPress site there are different set of changes you can make to your site from within your admin panel.

With a little effort it is easy to make your site as unique .

Here are some of the ways you can **customize your site** :-

- **How to Access the WordPress Customization Page**-

  To start customizing your WordPress theme, first go to Appearance -> Themes page..

[image]

- **How to Modify your WordPress Title and Tagline**-

  The theme customization page allows you to modify your site's title and tagline and see how it will look on your actual site immediately.

  To do this, expand the Site Title & Tagline group of settings and alter the text. As you type you will see the new text showing up in the preview on your right side.
- **More Customization Options**-

  Check out the following ways you can continue to personalize your site:-

  - Customize your **site’s header** and **background**
  - Tweak **fonts, colors**, and add **CSS** for a custom design
  - Change your **URL** by registering a new domain
  - Set a custom “Home” page on your site
  - Learn more about all your site settings

    [image]

> Here is the wordpress tutorial which will help you to customize a
>   wordpress theme -
>
> - [How to Customize WordPress Themes](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/customize-theme.htm)
> - [WordPress Theme Customizations](https://en.support.wordpress.com/customize/)
> - [Theme Customization API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/)

Comment: hello , thanx for your help . could you please help how to develop header and footer  of a custom page in wordpress .